# Localization of triangulated categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, triangulated-categories

I have been reading from the Stacks project, and Lemma 13.5.4. says:

> Let $F : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D}'$ be an exact functor of
>   **pre**-triangulated categories.  Let
>   $$
> S = \{f \in \text{Arrows}(\mathcal{D})
> \mid F(f)\text{ is an isomorphism}\}
> $$
>   Then $S$ is a saturated multiplicative system compatible with the
>   triangulated structure on $\mathcal{D}$.

I can't show that MS3 holds in S without using TR4 (specifically, existence of morphism $i$ in following diagram), but TR4 only holds in triangulated categories.

Could anyone explain to me why the diagram commutes without using TR4? Thanks.

\begin{array}
0Z &\stackrel{t}{\longrightarrow}& X &\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}& Q &\longrightarrow & Z[1] \\
&&\downarrow{id_x} &&\downarrow{i} \\
&&X &\stackrel{a}{\longrightarrow}& Y \\
&&&& \downarrow{j} \\
&&&& W
\end{array}

Comment: Is there something wrong with the proof given in the Stacks project? It seems very thorough about keeping track of which axioms it uses, and doesn't use TR4.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I just found the solution on a note on triangulated categories. The properties used there is not the same as in Stacks project, and I still don't know how to prove the existence of $i$ using the fact that functor $\mathop{\rm Hom}\nolimits_\mathcal{D}(-, W)$ is homological.